# How to create a form that adds text every odd column of row 1 in Excel VBA

Tags: forms, vba, excel

How to create a form that adds text in odd column of row 1 in Excel VBA. So basically I want to create a form that adds text from the text field in the form into Cell (1,1) when clicked on add button in the form and then clears the form for next entry. In the next entry text is added in Cell (1,4). How do you do that in VBA?

So lets say you have cell  (1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6) (1,7) (1,8) (1,9) (1,10) (1,11). I want the text to appear in cell (1,1) and merge it with (1,2) then I want to skip cell (1,3) and add the next entry in cell (1,4) and merge it with cell (1,5) and so on. How do I do that in VBA. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Few people will write the full code for you. Try to write it yourself, spliting your project in small steps, and googling each step. For example, its not clear if you know how to clear a textbox after "sending" the data, or if you want to know how to increase row number (by the way, cells are refered as `Cells(TheRow, TheColumn)`). Most people here are willing to answer _specific_ code problems, not to write a full module.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, I'm not a vba master but i wrote same code it works exactly. you just need to import this module and when you run it indicate column letter and row number where you want to begin input. for example cell A1 column letter A and row number 1. It's enter text in A1 merges it with A2 then skips one cell and next record will be in A4

http://www30.zippyshare.com/v/eRDoLeZO/file.html